# Birthday query in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, gql

I want to have a list of contact that celebrates their birthday disregarding the year, but I can't seem to disregard the year when I do `gql`.

The closest that I get is the code

`SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE birthdate = DATE(2013, 4, 5)`  and this code is very wrong.

I need something like a wildcard to put in `DATE(*, 4, 5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that there's an efficient way to query a `datetime.datetime` object on month/day using only `GQL`,

If this is a critical feature of the app which will be used frequently my advice would be to store birth year and birth month/day seperately in the datastore. You can then query the month/day directly.

Comment: Yes, my app has a birthday display & greeting feature. I think this is the only way aside from doing it in java by querying all the contacts and manually checking.